# What is the best way to create a nested opengl canvas

Tags: windows, linux, opengl, 3d, sdl

I would like to write a library that draws some opengl on a given window handle.

How can I initialize an opengl-context inside a given window?
Is it possible to do that platform independent using SDL or some other library?

Comment: How does the data structure for your given, platform independent window look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt provides a very good, cross platform mechanism for opening an OpenGL context and drawing into it.  For details, see [QtOpenGL](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtopengl.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Open Producer or the OpenSceneGraph to do it as well.